# new() in method

Tags: c#, generics

Having these classes:

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    DbContext GetContext();
}

public class Repo<T> : IRepo<T> where T : Entity, new()
{
    protected readonly DbContext c;
}

public Repo(IDbContextFactory f)
{
    c = f.GetContext();
}
```

What does the keyword `new()` (in `class Repo<T>`) do?

Answer (score 11):

It means that the type `T` must expose a public, default (i.e. parameterless) constructor. That is, you will be able to construct an instance of `T` with `new T()`. It can expose other constructors as well, but this generic constraint makes the default one mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

it means, the entity should have a parameterless public constructor.

see [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `where` keyword on a generic definition you apply a type contraint to the generic paramater. The `new()` constraint declares that the type, `T` in this case, must have a default constructor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx

---

After reading your [clarification disguised as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193343/659190) I thought I would try and help by clarifying a couple of things.

The code in your orginal question defines an interface that seemes to be used by a disembodied constructor. In between those two denfinitions you have defined a generic class which doesen't seem to do much.

Your question pertains to the generic class and the other two definitions are irrelavent to both the question and the answer.

Comment: English is not the OP's native language, I suspect. For many non-native speakers, make and do are confused. Someone has edited the question to this effect now.

Comment: @David M, deleted for clarity